# Conditional expectation of independent random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose $X, Y, Z$ are random variables and $X, Y$ are independent to each other. Can  I write $\mathrm{E}[XY|Z]=\mathrm{E}[X|Z] * \mathrm{E}[Y|Z]$ ?

Comment: Assume you are at home and you are about to apply the rule $$E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$$ for your independent random variables $X,Y$. And someone in the radio says $Z$ has been realized. So in order to take everything in account you write in your paper that everything from now on in the world happens conditionally on the realization of Z. Then will your rule seize to apply?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the given statement is true.  Let $X, Y$ be IID discrete uniform on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  Let $Z$ be $1$ if $X-Y = 2$, and $0$ otherwise.  Then ${\rm E}[XY \mid Z = 1] \ne {\rm E}[X \mid Z = 1]{\rm E}[Y \mid Z = 1]$.  In general, it is not too hard to see that if $Z$ is a nontrivial function of $X$ and $Y$, then $X \mid Z$ and $Y \mid Z$ are not necessarily independent even if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: ok, thank you. I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Toss a coin twice. Let $X=1$ if we get a toss on the first head, and $0$ otherwise. Let $Y=1$ if we get head on the second toss, and $0$ otherwise. Then $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Let $Z=X+Y$. If $Z=1$, then $XY=0$ with probability $1$, so $E(XY|Z=1)=0$.

But $E(X|Z=1)=E(Y|Z=1)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: This was the counterexample I had read on this site before (maybe even you were the one who wrote it!) but for some reason I could neither remember the details nor find where it had been previously posted...

Comment: It is quite possible I have written this before. Finding stuff on MSE is, for me, difficult.