# Given two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, are $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ and $E[Y|\mathcal{G}]$ independent necessarily?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

I know it is not necessarily true. We can construct simple coin tossing counterexamples as described on posts like [Conditional expectation of independent random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695162/conditional-expectation-of-independent-random-variables) before.

I'd like to take the question forward and seek a *measure-theoretic* way of reasoning about this and providing an appropriate enough description of the sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$ (with $\mathcal{F}$ being the $\sigma$-algebra on which the random variables are defined) detailing when we would have independence when we wouldn't. I have tried to do so by working with the definitions but have been unable to come to anything well-defined.

Considering the simple case of $X = 1_{A}$ and $Y= 1_{B}$ (essentially to make the $E$ operator indistinguishable from the $P$ operator and reason using the basic definition too. Also, using an MCT argument, we could extend from this case to more general RVs), we have

$$P(A \cap B) = E(1_{A\cap B}) = E[1_A \cdot 1_B] = E[X Y] = E[X]E[Y] = P(A)P(B) $$

For independence of $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ and $E[Y|\mathcal{G}]$, we are looking for 
$$E[E[X|\mathcal{G}]] \cdot E[E[Y|\mathcal{G}]] = E[E[X|\mathcal{G}]\cdot E[Y|\mathcal{G}] ]$$

A simple case where this relation would hold if $X$ and $Y$ were themselves $\mathcal{G}$ measurable, that is, $\sigma(X) \subset \mathcal{G}$ and $\sigma(Y) \subset \mathcal{G}$

For the other cases (in terms of containment relations between $\mathcal{G}$ and $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ and when they have 'no relation') I haven't been able to come up clear enough descriptions. 
*Apologies for the title of the question, given that it's already been answered. Just trying to get as many responses as possible.*

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking given that straightforward constructions show that this is not true in general. It is not clear what the connection is to the linked question (nor is there any coin tossing example provided). What is the purpose in getting other responses?

Comment: what do you mean by saying independent when you are talking about expected values?

Comment: @user144410: The OP is asking about condition expectations, which are random variables themselves.

Comment: @copper.hat ah okay, I thought these are realized! But then it seems to me that the independence hold. anktsdmcknsy can you show a counterexample?

Comment: @user144410: Let $X,Y$ be two independent coin tosses and let the $\sigma$-field be generated by $X=Y$.

Comment: @user144410 I've provided a link to a post with the counterexamaple .

Comment: @anktsdmcknsy: The link has no counterexample. In fact, it is not clear what the point of the link is.

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry, I amended the link. Click on it now.

Comment: Also, I am curious to understand why there has been a vote to close this question. I am not interested in simply providing a counterexample and moving on with the question. I am trying to get a more sound understanding from the theoretical view point, an understanding that I believe would be of value to others too.